# Qt Creator : Adding an external library (header file not found)

Tags: c++, c, header, qt-creator, qmake

This is my external library location in my `Qt` project (named `contr`):

[image]

This is my `makefile` :

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = contr
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += 3rdparty/libs/libusb

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

LIBS += -L"3rdparty/libs/libusb" -llibusb
```

In a file, I have this `include` :

```
#include <libusb.h>
```

When I compile, I get the following error :

```
mainwindow.cpp:3: erreur : C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libusb.h': No such file or directory
```

**EDIT** :

I work on `Windows`

Comment: the path you add to `INCLUDEPATH` needs to be relative from where ever your `.pro` file is. I don't see your `.pro` file in the screenshot above, so it must be somewhere else. You may need to start the path with `$$PWD/` which expands to the present working diretory

Comment: @yano : My `.pro` file is in the `contr` folder

Comment: oh ok .. Try prefacing with `$$PWD/` .. if that doesn't work, try an absolute path as a sanity check.

Comment: no dice? (must meet character min...)

Comment: It didn't change anything. I still get the error

Comment: add `message("INCLUDEPATH = "$$INCLUDEPATH)` underneath your `INCLUDEPATH += ...` statement,, that will show you in General Messages and Compile Output what the include path is. I would try an absolute path as a sanity check too. If that doesn't work my next guess would be folder/file permissions issues.

Comment: Here's what I get with a relative path : `Project MESSAGE: INCLUDEPATH = 3rdparty/libs/libusb`. I'll try an absolute path now

Comment: Here's what I get with the absolute path : `Project MESSAGE: INCLUDEPATH = C:/Users/TONPC/Documents/contr/3rdparty/libs/libusb`

Comment: you still get the error with the absolute path? If so I don't know what to tell you other than make sure the `.h` file is at that path and you have read permission on the directory and file.